# Why am I getting this TypeError on elemsTextBoxes.on('focus', function() {?

Tags: jquery, typeerror

In the following code, I can get a collection of input elements and color their background, but can't set an event on them. Whey do I get this error?

[image]

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        CONTACTFORM.initialize($("#formContact"));
    });
    var CONTACTFORM = CONTACTFORM || {};

    CONTACTFORM.initialize = function(form) {

        var elemsTextBoxes = form.find('input[type=text]');

        elemsTextBoxes.css('background-color', 'ddd'); //works

        elemsTextBoxes.on('focus', function() { //gets error
            $(this).css('background-color', '#eee'); 
        });
        elemsTextBoxes.on('blur', function() {
            $(this).css('background-color', '#fff'); 
        });
```

Comment: You are of course using jQuery 1.7+ ??

Comment: if you replace the function "on" by the function "bind" without changing anything else, does it work?

Comment: right adeneo, it was 1.4.4. which explains why it was working on another server and not this one, fixed, thanks.